# Simple php Math Objec (ABS method) - get 2 decimals

Tags: php, math, decimal, echo

I have a small difficulty with the php math object.
Whenever I echo a total number it will display okay with 2 decimals, except when the number has .00 it will not.
So 20.00 - 10.00 will display 10 while 20.00 - 9.99 will display 10.01

I would like to **always show 2 decimals**.

As I search the internet I cannot find the way to add it to my code. I think it should be done with a 'number_format($total_sub,2)' , but how?

See example code that parses the end number:

```
<?php 
$less_subtotal= '10.00';
$order_subtotal= '20.00';
$total_sub = abs($order_subtotal - $less_subtotal);  
number_format($total_sub, 2);// output is still witouth 2 decimals...
echo $total_sub;
?>
```

**--- EDIT ---**
As I described the posted I knew the problem.... EPIC..

```
echo number_format($total_sub, 2);
```

Should be okay now I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$less_subtotal= '10.00';
$order_subtotal= '20.00';
$total_sub = abs($order_subtotal - $less_subtotal);  
echo bcadd($total_sub,0,2);
?>


Just tested...
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not assigned the result of `number_format` to any variable. Assign back it to the variable

```
$total_sub=number_format($total_sub, 2);// output is still witouth 2 decimals...
echo $total_sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it works fine:

```
$less_subtotal= (float)10.00;
$order_subtotal= (float)20.00;
$total_sub = abs($order_subtotal - $less_subtotal);  
$total_sub = number_format($total_sub, 2);//assign number_format to variable
echo $total_sub;
```